# Exclude The Links From The Navigation Templates

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I know that I'm able to get the links to an article using [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Linkshere) in my API request.

My problem is regarding the [cases of inclusion](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:What_links_here#Cases_of_inclusion). By asking for the links to a specific article, I'm also getting the links in all of the `navigation templates` which are included at the bottom of the article.

For example, after asking for the links to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%A9phane_Sess%C3%A8gnon):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=St%C3%A9phane_Sess%C3%A8gnon&prop=linkshere
```

I'm also getting the links which appear at the bottom of the page, in the `navigation templates`:

[image]

I'm building an app which uses the mobile version of `Wikipedia`, so the `navigation templates` at the bottom of the pages are not relevant for my goal, because [they are not shown in the mobile version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Navbox_visibility).

**I'd like to exclude those links from the result someway. I want to get only the links which actually appears in an article body, or at least detect whether they are from a template or not. Is this possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that there is a [mobile API](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Mobile/get_page_mobile_sections_title_revision)? It does various transformations on the article to make it more appropriate for small-screen devices, including the removal of most navigation templates. For example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/mobile-sections/Fort_Horsted

```
{
  "lead": {
    "ns": 0,
    "id": 35265226,
    "revision": "803745099",
    "lastmodified": "2017-10-04T10:37:41Z",
    "lastmodifier": {
      "user": "InternetArchiveBot",
      "gender": "unknown"
    },
    "displaytitle": "Fort Horsted",
    "normalizedtitle": "Fort Horsted",
    "wikibase_item": "Q5471353",
    "protection": {},
    "editable": true,
    "languagecount": 0,
    "image": {
      "file": "The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg",
      "urls": {
        "320": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg",
        "640": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg",
        "800": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg",
        "1024": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg"
      }
    },
    "hatnotes": [],
    "geo": {
      "latitude": 51.358,
      "longitude": 0.513
    },
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "text": "<span><p><b>Fort Horsted</b> is a <a href=\"/wiki/Scheduled_monument\" title=\"Scheduled monument\">scheduled monument</a> (Monument Number 416040) that lies in the Horsted Valley to the South of <a href=\"/wiki/Chatham,_Kent\" title=\"Chatham, Kent\">Chatham, Kent</a>, England. It is a late 19th-century Land Fort, and one of six constructed around Chatham and <a href=\"/wiki/Gillingham,_Kent\" title=\"Gillingham, Kent\">Gillingham, Kent</a> to protect <a href=\"/wiki/Chatham_Dockyard\" title=\"Chatham Dockyard\">HM Dockyard Chatham</a> from attack. Originally  proposed in the <a href=\"/wiki/Royal_Commission_on_the_Defence_of_the_United_Kingdom\" title=\"Royal Commission on the Defence of the United Kingdom\">Royal Commission on the Defence of the United Kingdom</a> Report, published in 1860, it and the other land defences were omitted as part of general cost cutting with only the coastal defences on the <a href=\"/wiki/River_Medway\" title=\"River Medway\">River Medway</a> being retained and completed under the original 1860 proposals. It was not until the mid-1870s that a revised program was accepted, which included the construction of a convict prison at <a href=\"/wiki/Borstal,_Rochester\" title=\"Borstal, Rochester\">Borstal, Rochester</a>, to provide low cost labour for the construction of a line of four forts, <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Borstal\" title=\"Fort Borstal\">Fort Borstal</a>, <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Bridgewood\" title=\"Fort Bridgewood\">Fort Bridgewood</a>, Fort Horsted and <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Luton\" title=\"Fort Luton\">Fort Luton</a> (a further three forts were constructed with the use of convict labour). Its construction started in 1879 and was complete by 1889 after much delay.</p></span><figure class=\"mw-default-size\" id=\"mwAg\"><a href=\"/wiki/File:The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg\" class=\"image\"><img src=\"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg/220px-The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg\" data-file-type=\"bitmap\" height=\"163\" width=\"220\" srcset=\"//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg/440px-The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg 2x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg/330px-The_British_Army_in_the_United_Kingdom_1939-45_H5865.jpg 1.5x\"></a><figcaption>A <a href=\"/wiki/QF_12-pounder_12_cwt_AA_gun\" title=\"QF 12-pounder 12 cwt AA gun\">QF 12-pounder 12 cwt AA gun</a> mounted on Albion BY-series truck, December 1940</figcaption></figure>\n<p class=\"skipped\"><span style=\"font-size: small;\"></span></p>\n\n\n\n"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "anchor": "Materials",
        "line": "Materials"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "anchor": "Armaments",
        "line": "Armaments"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "anchor": "World_wars",
        "line": "World wars"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "anchor": "The_name",
        "line": "The name"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "anchor": "The_fort_today",
        "line": "The fort today"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "anchor": "References",
        "line": "References"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "toclevel": 1,
        "anchor": "External_links",
        "line": "External links"
      }
    ]
  },
  "remaining": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "text": "\n<p>The fort was constructed almost entirely of <a href=\"/wiki/Concrete\" title=\"Concrete\">concrete</a>, topped with <a href=\"/wiki/Chalk\" title=\"Chalk\">chalk</a> and <a href=\"/wiki/Soil\" title=\"Soil\">earth</a> with no visible concrete exposed from the outside, except from the gorge or rear of the fort. The ditch was protected by two single and one double counterscarp galleries.</p>\n\n",
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "Materials",
        "anchor": "Materials"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "text": "\n<p>Although the original plans of the fort proposed fixed armament, by its completion there had been a shift away from fixed armament to moveable guns. The fort would not been armed, unless actual threat materialised and then with moveable field artillery. In the event of actual invasion and an attack on HM Dockyard Chatham, additional field defence would have augmented the forts, with trenches and battery positions. In fact in 1907 during summer manoeuvres such defences were probably constructed.</p>\n\n",
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "Armaments",
        "anchor": "Armaments"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "text": "\n<p>Deemed to have become obsolete by 1910, the fort formed part of Chatham's land defences in both World Wars. In <a href=\"/wiki/World_War_I\" title=\"World War I\">World War I</a> brick emplacements and a <a href=\"/wiki/Pillbox_(military)\" title=\"Pillbox (military)\">pillbox</a> were built on the ramparts, and fixed <a href=\"/wiki/Anti-aircraft_gun\" title=\"Anti-aircraft gun\" class=\"mw-redirect\">anti-aircraft guns</a> of an early type were installed (possibly 12pdr coastal defence guns on improvised high angle mountings, not be confused with the later naval version).</p>\n\n",
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "World wars",
        "anchor": "World_wars"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "text": "\n<p>The fort was named after a local hamlet. Horsted is speculated to have been named after the legendary Saxon warrior <a href=\"/wiki/Horsa\" title=\"Horsa\" class=\"mw-redirect\">Horsa</a>, who was killed at nearby <a href=\"/wiki/Battle_of_Aylesford\" title=\"Battle of Aylesford\">Aylesford</a> while fighting the Britons.<span class=\"mw-ref\" id=\"cite_ref-1\"><a href=\"#cite_note-1\" style=\"counter-reset: mw-Ref 1;\"><span class=\"mw-reflink-text\">[1]</span></a></span></p>\n\n",
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "The name",
        "anchor": "The_name"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "text": "\n<p>The fort survives relatively intact and is currently in use as a <a href=\"/wiki/Business_park\" title=\"Business park\">business park</a>. While it is in relatively good condition, its commercial use has seen some new construction and modification which has seen the significant loss of the original structure and features.</p>\n\n",
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "The fort today",
        "anchor": "The_fort_today"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "text": "\n<div class=\"mw-references-wrap\"><ol class=\"mw-references references\"><li id=\"cite_note-1\"> <span id=\"mw-reference-text-cite_note-1\" class=\"mw-reference-text\"><cite class=\"citation web\" id=\"mwLA\"><a rel=\"mw:ExtLink\" href=\"https://www.britannica.com/topic/Hengist\" class=\"external\">\"Hengist and Horsa\"</a>. Encyclopædia Britannica.</cite></span></li></ol></div>\n\n\n",
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "References",
        "anchor": "References",
        "isReferenceSection": true
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "text": "\n<ul><li> <a rel=\"mw:ExtLink\" href=\"http://www.ecastles.co.uk/chatham.html\" class=\"external\">Map of Chatham's defences</a></li>\n<li> <a rel=\"mw:ExtLink\" href=\"http://www.forthorsted.co.uk/content/history\" class=\"external\">Fort Horsted website history page</a></li>\n<li> <a rel=\"mw:ExtLink\" href=\"https://web.archive.org/web/20120410012117/http://www.undergroundkent.co.uk/fort_horsted.htm\" class=\"external\">Fort Horsted on the Underground Kent website</a> Dead Link</li>\n<li> <a rel=\"mw:ExtLink\" href=\"http://www.pastscape.org.uk/hob.aspx?hob_id=416040&amp;sort=2&amp;type=&amp;rational=a&amp;class1=1&amp;period=None&amp;county=693349&amp;district=786118&amp;parish=None&amp;place=chatham&amp;recordsperpage=10&amp;source=text&amp;rtype=&amp;rnumber=&amp;p=2&amp;move=n&amp;nor=39&amp;recfc=0\" class=\"external\">Pastscape Record Fort Horstead</a></li></ul>\n\n<div role=\"navigation\" class=\"navbox\" aria-labelledby=\"Forts_in_Medway\" style=\"padding:3px\"><table class=\"nowraplinks collapsible autocollapse navbox-inner\" style=\"border-spacing:0;background:transparent;color:inherit\"><tbody><tr><th scope=\"col\" class=\"navbox-title\" colspan=\"2\" style=\"background:lightsteelblue;\"><div class=\"plainlinks hlist navbar mini\"><ul><li class=\"nv-view\"><a href=\"/wiki/Template:Defences_of_medway\" title=\"Template:Defences of medway\"><abbr style=\";background:lightsteelblue;;background:none transparent;border:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;\">v</abbr></a></li><li class=\"nv-talk\"><a href=\"/wiki/Template_talk:Defences_of_medway\" title=\"Template talk:Defences of medway\"><abbr style=\";background:lightsteelblue;;background:none transparent;border:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;\">t</abbr></a></li><li class=\"nv-edit\"><a rel=\"mw:ExtLink\" href=\"//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Defences_of_medway&amp;action=edit\" class=\"external\"><abbr style=\";background:lightsteelblue;;background:none transparent;border:none;-moz-box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none;box-shadow:none;\">e</abbr></a></li></ul></div><div id=\"Forts_in_Medway\" style=\"font-size:114%;margin:0 4em\">Forts in Medway</div></th></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\" class=\"navbox-list navbox-odd hlist\" style=\"width:100%;padding:0px\"><div style=\"padding:0em 0.25em\">\n<dl><dt>Medieval</dt>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Rochester_Castle\" title=\"Rochester Castle\">Rochester Castle</a></dd></dl>\n\n<dl><dt>Tudor</dt>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Upnor_Castle\" title=\"Upnor Castle\">Upnor Castle</a></dd></dl>\n\n<dl><dt>17th century</dt>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Cockham_Wood_Fort\" title=\"Cockham Wood Fort\">Cockham Wood Fort</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Gillingham\" title=\"Fort Gillingham\">Fort Gillingham</a></dd></dl>\n\n<dl><dt>Inner Ring <span style=\"font-weight:normal;\">(Napoleonic)</span></dt>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Clarence\" title=\"Fort Clarence\">Fort Clarence</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Pitt,_Kent\" title=\"Fort Pitt, Kent\">Fort Pitt</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Amherst\" title=\"Fort Amherst\">Fort Amherst</a></dd></dl>\n\n<dl><dt>Outer Ring <span style=\"font-weight:normal;\">(<a href=\"/wiki/Royal_Commission_on_the_Defence_of_the_United_Kingdom\" title=\"Royal Commission on the Defence of the United Kingdom\">Palmerston</a>)</span></dt>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Borstal\" title=\"Fort Borstal\">Fort Borstal</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Bridgewood\" title=\"Fort Bridgewood\">Fort Bridgewood</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Darland\" title=\"Fort Darland\">Fort Darland</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Horsted\" title=\"Fort Horsted\">Fort Horsted</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Luton\" title=\"Fort Luton\">Fort Luton</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Grange_Redoubt\" title=\"Grange Redoubt\">Grange Redoubt</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Woodlands_Redoubt\" title=\"Woodlands Redoubt\">Woodlands Redoubt</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Hoo\" title=\"Fort Hoo\">Fort Hoo</a></dd>\n<dd> <a href=\"/wiki/Fort_Darnet\" title=\"Fort Darnet\">Fort Darnet</a></dd></dl>\n</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div>\n\n",
        "toclevel": 1,
        "line": "External links",
        "anchor": "External_links"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

(The response for [Stéphane Sessègnon](https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/mobile-sections/St%C3%A9phane_Sess%C3%A8gnon) would be too large to include here.)

If you really just want the links, and only non-template ones, I don't think that's available. You can parse it yourself, using something like [mwparserfromhell](https://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)